# Issue with Accessing D365 Business Central using user_impersonation permission

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, dynamics-business-central, microsoft-teams-js, businesscentral

I am developing Microsoft Teams BOT using yo Teams and node.

The requirement is to access the Business Central using the BOT to fetch the environment with the user's delegated permission.

I am able to configure the BOT, App service and also able to fetch the current logged-in users details.

But the scp parameter of the Access Token is not returning the user_impersonation scope in int. hence, it's not working for me to access the Business Central.

Here are the screenshot of the permission.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am using microsoft-graph-client library to perform this API Call.

Comment: Could you please ensure that your app requests `user_impersonation` scope during the sign-in process? This is typically done by including `user_impersonation` in the scope parameter of your authorization request.

Comment: How can i check that? I am using Node version of yo teams.

Comment: In the Node.js version of yo teams, you can do this by modifying the authorization request in your code.  const authUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}&scope=${encodeURIComponent('user_impersonation')}&state=${state}&nonce=${nonce}&response_mode=fragment&prompt=consent`;

Comment: `user_impersonation` is included in the `scope` parameter of the authorization URL. This URL is used to redirect the user to the Azure AD sign-in page. After the user signs in, Azure AD redirects the user back to your app with an access token in the URL fragment.

Comment: Getting this error:
Missing required query string parameter: code. Url = https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

Comment: This error might be due to a misconfiguration in your bot's OAuth settings. Please check your bot's OAuth settings in the Azure portal. Make sure that you have correctly set up an OAuth connection, with the correct provider, client id, client secret, and scopes

Comment: Ensure that the 'OAuth Connection Settings' in your bot's settings in the Azure portal is correctly configured. The 'Redirect URL' should be set to 'https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect'.

Comment: It is correct, I have double checked this. THe main requirement is to have the delegated permission user_impersonation used to call the business central API fro the BOT. And I think that is the thing which is not working. I am able to get the access token with scope Finanical.Readwrite.All but when I am adding user_impoersonation as a scope,its not working.

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you are making the authorization request, and what values you're passing (e.g. in the scope parameter)?

Comment: The requirement is to get both the scopes for Graph and Business central get in single access token and where I am getting the error.